# Spring Boot 3.2 REST API Call with Generic Response: Type Mismatch Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, resttemplate, java-17

I am working on a Spring Boot application (version 3.2) where I make an external API call using the `RestClient` class. The `updateProduct` method in my service class invokes the external API and returns a generic response using the `invokeAPI` method. However, I'm facing an issue where the `APIResponseDTO` result type is not correctly inferred as `ProductDTO` but rather as `LinkedHashMap`.

Here's the relevant code:

```java
    public APIResponseDTO<ProductDTO> updateProduct(@NonNull ProductRequestDTO productRequest) {
        return invokeAPI(productRequest, HttpMethod.PUT, ProductDTO.class);
    }
    
    public <T, R> APIResponseDTO<T> invokeAPI(R requestDTO, HttpMethod httpMethod, Class<T> responseType) {
        Class<?> responseDTOClass = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructParametricType(APIResponseDTO.class, responseType).getRawClass();
        String productAPI = apiURL + apiVersion + PRODUCTS_API;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("client_id", apiClientId);
        headers.set("client_secret", apiClientSecret);
        Function<Boolean, String> accessTokenFunction = (forceRefresh) -> fetchAccessTokenResponse(forceRefresh).getAccessToken();
        return (APIResponseDTO<T>) restClient.exchange(productAPI,
                                                                          requestDTO,
                                                                          httpMethod,
                                                                          headers,
                                                                          responseDTOClass,
                                                                          accessTokenFunction,
                                                                          GatewayException.class);
    }
```

And here are the relevant DTOs:

```java
@Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class APIResponseDTO<T> {
        @JsonProperty("status")
        private boolean status;

        @JsonProperty("errorCode")
        private int errorCode;

        @JsonProperty("errorMsg")
        private String errorMsg;

        @JsonProperty("result")
        private T result;
    }


    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class ProductDTO {
        @JsonProperty("id")
        private String id;
    }
```

Below is the `Restclient`

```
import java.net.URI;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.function.Function;
    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
    import org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate;
    import org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException;
    import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

    @Slf4j
    public class RestClient extends RestTemplate {

        public static final String BEARER = "Bearer ";
        public static final boolean TOKEN_CACHE_ENABLED = true;
        public static final boolean TOKEN_CACHE_DISABLED = false;
        private final RetryTemplate retryTemplate;
        
        public <T> ResponseEntity<T> execute(
            String uri,
            HttpMethod method,
            HttpEntity<?> requestEntity,
            Class<T> responseType,
            Function<Boolean, String> accessTokenFunction) {
            
            ResponseEntity<T> responseEntity =
                    retryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> super.exchange(uri, method, requestEntity, responseType));
            
            if (responseEntity != null && responseEntity.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) {
                // If the response status is 401, retry with a new access token
                log.warn("Received 401 response from Salesforce. Retrying with a new access token.");
                requestEntity.getHeaders().set(AUTHORIZATION, BEARER + accessTokenFunction.apply(TOKEN_CACHE_DISABLED));
                responseEntity = exchange(uri, method, requestEntity, responseType);
            }
            return responseEntity;
        }

        public <T, R, E extends RuntimeException> Object exchange(
                String apiUrl,
                T requestDTO,
                HttpMethod httpMethod,
                HttpHeaders headers,
                Class<?> responseType,
                Function<Boolean, String> accessTokenFunction,
                Class<E> exceptionClass) {
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.set(AUTHORIZATION, BEARER + accessTokenFunction.apply(TOKEN_CACHE_ENABLED));
            HttpEntity<T> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestDTO, headers);
            ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity =
                    execute(apiUrl, httpMethod, requestEntity, responseType, accessTokenFunction);
            if (responseEntity != null
                    && responseEntity.getStatusCode().value() >= HttpStatus.OK.value()
                    && responseEntity.getStatusCode().value() <= HttpStatus.IM_USED.value()) {
                return responseEntity.getBody();
            } else {
                log.error("Failed to fetch the Response: {} for API {} | HttpMethod {} ", responseEntity, apiUrl, httpMethod);
                throw new CustomException(exceptionClass,"Failed to fetch the Response: " + responseEntity + " for API " + apiUrl + " | HttpMethod "+ httpMethod);
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems that the `invokeAPI` method is not correctly maintaining the generic type information for the `result` field in `APIResponseDTO`. Instead of the expected `ProductDTO`, it returns a `LinkedHashMap`.

[image]

I suspect the issue might be related to the use of `TypeFactory.defaultInstance()`, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Any help or suggestions on fixing this type mismatch issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Additionally, I find myself using a type cast (APIResponseDTO) in the invokeAPI method. I'm looking for a cleaner way to handle this and avoid explicit type casting. Specifically, is there a way to modify the exchange method to return a generic response instead of Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ParameterizedTypeReference` specifically for responses that involve collections or custom objects with generics. This preserves crucial type information at runtime, ensuring accurate deserialization of these parameterized types.

So, you can test the request like this:

```
var responseEntity = execute(apiUrl, httpMethod, new HttpEntity<>(requestDTO),
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<APIResponseDTO<ProductDTO>>() {
    });
```

And this is the debug result I tested (I needed to use my own DTO for alignment with my downstream testing API:

[image]

For the updated custom RestClient bean code, it would look like this:

```
@Component
public class MyRestClient extends RestTemplate {

  public <T> ResponseEntity<T> execute(
      String uri,
      HttpMethod method,
      HttpEntity<?> requestEntity,
      ParameterizedTypeReference<T> responseType) {
    return super.exchange(uri, method, requestEntity, responseType);
  }

  public <T, R> R exchange(
      String apiUrl,
      T requestDTO,
      HttpMethod httpMethod,
      ParameterizedTypeReference<R> responseType) {
    var responseEntity = execute(apiUrl, httpMethod, new HttpEntity<>(requestDTO), responseType);
    if (responseEntity != null
        && responseEntity.getStatusCode().value() >= HttpStatus.OK.value()
        && responseEntity.getStatusCode().value() <= HttpStatus.IM_USED.value()) {
      return responseEntity.getBody();
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
  }
}
```

And you can use the client for request like this: (However, you can adjust it in your own way)

```
  private static <T> ParameterizedTypeReference<APIResponseDTO<T>> getParameterizedTypeReference(
      Class<T> clazz) {
    return new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
      @Override
      public Type getType() {
        return new ParameterizedType() {
          @Override
          public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
            return new Type[]{clazz};
          }

          @Override
          public Type getRawType() {
            return APIResponseDTO.class;
          }

          @Override
          public Type getOwnerType() {
            return null;
          }
        };
      }
    };
  }

  public <T, R> APIResponseDTO<T> invokeAPI(R requestDTO, HttpMethod httpMethod,
      Class<T> responseType) {
    String productAPI = apiURL + apiVersion + PRODUCTS_API;
    var responseDTOClass = getParameterizedTypeReference(responseType);
    return restClient.exchange(
        productAPI,
        requestDTO,
        httpMethod,
        responseDTOClass
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible to make `invokeAPI()` generic without `APIResponseDTO` as return type so that  `invokeAPI()` can be invoked by multiple services where each service will have separate response types like   `Service1APIResponseDTO` `Service2APIResponseDTO`

Comment: It might not be the best solution, but you can do something like adding the new parameter for `getParameterizedTypeReference()` so it would be like this `<T, U> ParameterizedTypeReference<U> getParameterizedTypeReference(
      Class<T> clazz, Class<U> mainClazz)` and you can use mainClazz for the returning value of `getRawType()` and when you use `invokeAPI()` to get product you need to cast the result like this `var product = (ProductDTO) apiResponseDTO.getResult();`